# How to inject java instances into PHP scripts programmatically executed using Quercus

Tags: java, quercus

I have some code similar to this:

```
QuercusEngine engine = new QuercusEngine();
Value value = engine.execute("<?php return $obj->getName(); ?>");
System.out.println(value);
```

(See [http://wiki.caucho.com/Quercus:_Command_Line_Interface_(CLI)](http://wiki.caucho.com/Quercus%3a_Command_Line_Interface_%28CLI%29) for more info)

I want to set `$obj` as a java instance.  Something like this:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
engine.setParam("obj", someObject);
```

Obviously this is a simplistic example but the point is that I want to be able to use instances of java classes *that have already been instantiated* in the php script.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is documented anywhere, but after looking through the source code, looking at what the QuercusEngine was doing, and a little trial and error this is what it takes:

```
Path path = new StringPath("<?php return $obj->getName(); ?>");
QuercusContext quercusContext = new QuercusContext();
ReadStream reader = path.openRead();
QuercusProgram program = QuercusParser.parse(quercusContext, null, reader);
WriteStream out = new WriteStream(StdoutStream.create());
QuercusPage page = new InterpretedPage(program);

Env env = new Env(quercusContext, page, out, null, null);

SomeObject someObj = new SomeObject();

JavaClassDef classDef = env.getJavaClassDefinition(someObject.getClass());
env.setGlobalValue("obj", new JavaValue(env, someObject, classDef));

Value value = NullValue.NULL;

try {
  value = program.execute(env);
}
catch (QuercusExitException e) {
}

out.flushBuffer();
out.free();

System.out.println(value);
```

Hope this helps someone.  I tested this in Quercus 4.0.25.